# Making Foreach Async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, foreach

Consider a scenario where we have to call a method which in turns call database foreach object in list.

```
List<object> Response= new List<object>
foreach(object obj in List<object>)
{
    Resposne.add(callMethod());
}
```

How to run this foreach loop async, I want to call callmethod for next object in the list without waiting for first object call to return. Once all the calls are successfully returned control should go back to client.

As callMethod function is calling database sequential execution will take time. To improve performance I need to run this async.

Comment: Something like [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx)?

Comment: I hope that code is just a bad example because it doesn’t do anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to call callmethod for next object in the list without waiting for first object call to return.

You really want to [parallelize your loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<object> Response= new List<object>();
// You need to put some stuff on Response
Parallel.ForEach(Response, o =>
{
   Response.Add(callMethod());
});
```

Comment: While the idea of your solution is correct, I would strongly suggest using a lock before adding items to the shared list object. Or alternatively use a different version of the Parallel.ForEach loop which uses a thread/partition-local variable. And as a minor note: it should be `Parallel.ForEach(someVariableName, ...`.

Comment: I am calling external database in CallMethod(). I think parllel will not increase the performance.

Comment: Don't use `Parallel.Foreach` for IO operations. It will keep creating new threads while the existing ones wait for IO to finish.

Comment: @JakubLortz: Depends on your .NET Runtime, but probably not going to spin up too many threads.  It is pretty smart about how many threads to create.  You can also explicitly cap threads if you need to (using a different overload).

Comment: @manthandavda: That depends entirely on your external database.  For one data task I run, calling the database with 6 parallel threads gives me ideal throughput.  Chances are > 1 thread will improve performance.

Comment: @EricJ.These threads will still waste resources waiting for the IO to complete. It will work fine in a client application, but it will kill a server app. The right way to handle IO is to use async. Even if we're talking about a client app, it's better to get used to doing it correctly.

Comment: I disagree that async is inherently "the right way".  So does MSDN. `In most applications using async will have no noticeable benefits and even could be detrimental. Use tests, profiling and common sense to measure the impact of async in your particular scenario before committing to it.`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx  This being a client app, with no obvious UI thread involved, I would not rush to async.

Answer (score 2):

Your `callMethod()` is an IO operation, so don't use `Parallel.Foreach'.

`Parallel.Foreach` is designed for parallel computing. It scales well when you want to perform parallel CPU-intensive operations. However, if you call a synchronous IO operation, the thread will be blocked waiting for the operation to complete. It's a waste of resources, because the thread can't be reused when it's blocked. What's even worse, the scheduler will keep creating new threads for the `Parallel.Foreach' to keep the CPU busy. It might not be a very big issue in client applications, but in server applications with many concurrent requests it will be a bottleneck.

You should make your `callMethod()` asynchronous

```
private async Task<int> callMethodAsync()
```

In the method make an asynchronous operation, for example

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
```

Then use it like this:

```
int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(from obj in list select callMethodAsync());
```

Comment: Problem is i am using postgres and my datareader is not async.

Comment: @manthandavda what do you use to connect to the db? Npgsql has all necessary async methods.